# Converting degrees to X,Y coordinates with OpenLayers?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, convert, degrees-minutes-seconds

I have been tasked to center an openlayer map using the coordinates from an input.

My problem is that the coordinates are given in the degrees form.

For instance : 16° 58' 22" N 60° 17' 35" E

For now I achieved to center the map with X,Y coordinates (lat long I guess ?)

```
const coords = proj.fromLonLat([xCoord, yCoord]);
map.getView().animate({ center: coords, zoom: 10 });
```

But what I need is to transform the above degrees coordinates to an X,Y format for the code to work.

(I'm using openlayers v4.6.5)

---

This question has been marked as duplicate of [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73285/118356) but I can't get the answer to work properly.

For the following example coordonates **48 51' 14" N 2 20' 48" E**
I called the *getDecimalDeg()* method (provided in the answer) with the following parameters : **48, 51, 14** and a second time with **2, 20, 48**

I got : **480.850.0038888888888888888** and **9793:55 20.33333333333333330.013333333333333334**

I guess I'm using it wrong.

Comment: so the question is "how can I transform coordinates in degrees-minutes-seconds to decimal degrees"

Comment: @JGH well I'm no map expert so I can't confirm that what I need is called "decimal degrees" but it seems right ! Though I would like to use an openlayer fonctionnality to do the convertion. Your possible duplicate question uses a custom method as an answer. But maybe OL doesn't have what I'm looking for !

Comment: @JGH I find strange that OL has a .toStringHDMS(coordinate); method but not the other way around...